# Mapping models from client and server Rest API

Tags: rest, typescript, client-server, restful-architecture

I am doing in a project using client-server communication through rest API, Angular 2 calling restful web service, for specific.
On client side, it is written in Typescript, a sub set of javascript.

My problem is our object on the server side is nested, complex and difficult to model/ deserialize exactly on the client side when it receives a response (JSON object)

My question is:

1. Do we need to make a class on the client side for all json
   response object and deserialize them before binding it to the HTML
   view or processing data?
2. And how big/complex could the response JSON object become a problem?
   (Performance, Best practices...)
3. I am still confusing on how to share workload between client and server. What decides "we should handle it on server side" or "we should let the client do this"? Many of the cases I could let the server side fetch a lot of data before returning to clients, or should I let the client make multiple requests and fetch it on its side? 
   My application is probably an intranet application for ~ 1000 users (about 5-10 concurrently).

I am new to web application using rest, so I am greatly thank you if you guys could instruct me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer to subquestion #3. I develop microservice architecture for a small project and have faced the same problem. It's possible to implement logic either at server side or at client side.

At one hand server could return simple plain objects, at another - could return objects containing all necessary nested and processed data.

In the first case, client should make more queries to the server in order to collect all nested data. The client should be more complex and foresee all the situations when server data could be changed during series of requests (keeping the consistency of data). But it really simplifies the server implementation - it could be just series of CRUD repositories. It could be even auto generated server over underlying DB.

In the second case, server returns complex nested object. It allows to simplify client, since JSON deserialization is pretty straightforward with modern frameworks. It reduces number of queries to server. If a client could have all the necessary data in one query - that's great.

In both cases the business logic should be implemented somewhere. I vote for the simple client and hiding complexity at server side. Finally, for one server could be several clients. That's why complex server will be more beneficial than complex client.